# How do you edit a branch in Git?

Tags: version-control, github, branch, git-branch, git-bash

Coming from a SVN world, wrapping my head around Git has been a little weird, and I'm having trouble letting go of some of the practices ingrained in me from using Subversion for so long. So, for example, in SVN a branching structure might look like this:

-Trunk

--Master

-Branches

--SomeFeatureBranchA

--SomeFeatureBranchB

So, in this situation my Master branch has it's own set of code, and once I check out SomeFeatureBranchA & SomeFeatureBranchB, they'll have their own code. However, when I create a branch in Git, I see my branch listed, but at this point I'm unsure of how to edit the code for that branch.

Do I clone that branch down & simply rename it like:

-Trunk

--Master

--SomeFeatureBranchA

Or is there some command I'm missing that handles this for me?

Thanks for taking your time to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

`git branch` will tell you which branch you're currently on (as will `git status`).  Just edit as you normally do, if you're on the right branch.  If you're on the wrong branch `git checkout` *some branch* will get you there.  The top of the git repository is the equivalent of subversion `/trunk` or `/branches/SomeFeatureBranchA`.

Answer (score 0):

Forget everything you know about SVN when working with Git. You described your problem by comparing it with SVN, which makes it pretty difficult to understand what your problem actually is.

You created a branch in git (either with `git branch <name>` or `git checkout -b <name>`) and made it your active branch. Simply start hacking away at the code to edit your branch. When you're done, stage (read "add") and commit your changes, then push them at a later time if you're working with a remote tracking repository.

Does that answer your question? If not, can you please clarify what exactly it is you're trying to do?